# Kartik Select 2 Multiple not working with Dynamic Form

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, dynamicform

I have done everything I have found to solve the Select2 problem with the Dynamic form and it is working. But in this case, I need to use the Multiple option in the Select2 and that's what is not working.

[image: Multiple Select2 Not Working on Dynamic Form]

Select 2 Code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <?=
  $form->field($model_periodo, "[{$i}]id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
   'name' => 'periodo_dropdown',
   'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Periodo::find()->all(), 'id', 'descripcion'),
   'options' => [
    'multiple' => true,
    'placeholder' => 'Seleccione a el periodo',
    'value' => '',
   ],
  ])->label('Periodo');
 ?>
</div>
```

Note: When i set 'multiple' to false, it works just fine, because i've already done the JS changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a solution you found right now ? I am in this situation now that multiple not working.

Comment: sadly, the solution was changing the requirement with the client, and separate this two widgets.

Answer (score 0):

we are in the same situation, I've done everything to fix the Select2 in the dynamic form and nothing work, the loading icon keeps spinning forever and if I click the add new row button it doesn't work

this is what I get in the console

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #tblinvsalidasdetprods-{$i}-cod_producto
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1468)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2125)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2546)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:869)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2792)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2909)
at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (create:1389)
at fire (jquery.js:3187)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
```

but if remove the [{$i}] from my code it works

```
<?= $form->field($newmddet, 'cod_producto')->widget
                            (
                                Select2::classname(),
                                [
                                    'data'          => ArrayHelper::map
                                    (
                                        TblInvProductos::find()
                                        ->Where(['cod_empresa'=>$codEmpresa,'cod_estatus'=>'1'])
                                        ->OrderBy(['cod_prod_visible'=>SORT_DESC])
                                        ->all(),
                                        'cod_producto','NomProdConcat'
                                    ),
                                    'language'      => 'es',
                                    'options'       => ['placeholder' => 'Producto'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => 
                                    [
                                        'allowClear' => false
                                    ],
                                ]
                            )
                            ->Label(false);
                        ?>
```